# Windows Batch File for Login Shortcut

Tags: windows, batch-file, authentication

I know you can use tsdiscon.exe and tscon.exe to connect to a user account via the command line.

I want to write a simple batch file to accomplish this, so I can have a shortcut on my desktop that will quickly and easily login to another user account on this system.

I share this computer with my in-laws, and they are not very computer literate. Currently there are many steps in switching to their account, and I want to make it more streamlined for them.

It's been awhile since I've written a batch file, but I am sure there is a way to run a simple IF/THEN statement, that would check to see if the user is logged in, then either log them in with the given credentials, or switch to that users profile.

I want to know the syntax to make this happen, so I can put the .bat file on the desktop for them to click on.

Is this possible?

Comment: What version of windows and is it a "home" or "pro"?

Comment: Windows 10 Professional

Comment: On older windows versions it was <windows key> + L & fast user switching feature is turned on) and select user from list - that would do what you wanted. For Win 10 are you doing "method 1" described in http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/fast-user-switching-in-windows-10/f08cc777-8c33-4e43-a6c8-347409402f3e?auth=1 I don't see many steps, so how many steps are you doing?

I also have a batch script that can switch users via tscon but you have to store passwords in script file or enter it manually and tscon only works when running with administrator rights

Comment: That's exactly what I want, a batch file with passwords saved in the script file for switching quickly. We would only ever be running it from my or my wifes account, and we both have admin rights. I would love to grab that batch file off you!

Comment: What I did in the meantime is do a quick regedit and disable the Windows 10 Lock Screen. This cuts down on a step, and lets them click the Switch User shortcut I set up for them (essentially just a shortcut for tsdiscon) which takes them right to the user select screen and they type in their password.

Answer (score 0):

Logging out to your account? Suppose impossible.

Suppose your user is `usr1` and you save your batch file to, say, your desktop.
Then, by running this batch file, you run it as `usr1`.
If your batch file contains the log out statement, it therefore ends the user account, therefore terminating the batch file, thus not being able to run the batch file successfully.

However, switching to a different account **could be** possible.
Try [this](http://lifehacker.com/290435/switch-user-accounts-from-the-command-prompt) out, if it works.
Essentially, you're doing the following:

```
@echo off
taskkill /IM explorer.exe /F
runas /user:COMPUTERNAME\ACCOUNTNAME explorer.exe
```

(Replace `COMPUTERNAME` and `ACCOUNTNAME` with the current computer name and account name (i.e. `C:\Users\ACCOUNTNAME`) of your in-laws account)

If that's not what you wish, then, sorry, I can't help you.

Comment: I only ever want it to switch to another account, not logout the current session. This would let me access explorer as if I was them, but not log me into their actual desktop.

Comment: I'm just thinking now, if all I want to do is connect to their account without logging out, isn't there a way I could just make a shortcut on the desktop to tscon.exe with the applicable parameters? And would that switch to their desktop like they were logging in?

Answer (score 0):

The batch script I previously mentioned [here](https://github.com/sryper/2-click-fus)
Just give your machine a simple name customise one line in script. Test from command prompt:
    fus
If it works with win10 you should be able to create two shortcuts with commands:

fus.bat 1

and

fus.bat 2

Comment: Thanks for this :)

I customized the code, and added my computer name. I see that this requires the user to already be logged in. This will come in handy when they are running in the background. Thanks!

Comment: Your welcome please mark answer useful if you are agreeable. Let me know if notice any problems with win10. Yes, unfortunately you still need to be manually logged at least once since system boot for each user after that it's a one-click switch - I am not aware of any way to overcome that. You might want to set up a "<win> + 1" hot key. I use TWI (http://www.thewonderfulicon.com) but not sure if hot-keys still work under win10.

Comment: Pretty new to batch code.. So I tried to edit it. I changed the computer name.. But didn't know if usr1 and usr2 were placeholders or variables.. So I changed those to the usernames of the various accounts and added in the passwords.. But that didn't seem to work.

Comment: I'm sure there would be a way to make it an if/then situation where it'll switch to their account if they are logged in.. Otherwise if that session isn't found, it'll just kick you back to the login screen?